# Getting TLS details from Python Selenium logs

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am new to Selenium and have been trying to get the SSL details from Selenium logs. I do the following to enable logs:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
DriverCaps = driver.capabilities`

After filtering on Network.responseReceived, I am unable to find the actual client response to get the certificate details.

I can get details like:

```
{"message":{"method":"Network.responseReceived","params":{"frameId":"1DE9B13FA9784DEF3D1DC304C7558B69","loaderId":"E2FDEB2DF4A3EFCBEAA713F3E7E5289D","requestId":"E2FDEB2DF4A3EFCBEAA713F3E7E5289D",..."issuer": "GeoTrust RSA CA 2018"
```

Issuer information is what I need, but unfortunately, I cannot single out the actual client request among the sea of all the intermediate CDN requests. I would like to know if there is any unique identifier that I can use to get the actual request/response to get to the certificate info I see on the website (after driver.get).

Stuck on this for 2 days.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance.